# What are the dangers of using an out-of-support version of Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-10.10, mythbuntu

For my Home Theater PC, which also does a few other basic Linux tasks, I installed MythBuntu 10.10 back when it was the newest version (some time between October 2010 and April 2011, I don't remember exactly).
Since then, I have not done a distribution upgrade; I have kept up with updates, and used some PPAs for getting the latest versions of some packages.

Ubuntu 10.10 has just apparently dropped out of official support, but I am worried about doing a distribution upgrade to 11.04 or later because "it ain't broke". Everything works exactly as I need it to work, and I've heard horror stories about automated dist-upgrades of Ubuntu going awry.

As long as I'm otherwise vigilant about security, is it really that dangerous to continue running version 10.10 on this machine for the foreseeable future?
What are some issues I may come across?

Comment: Is this computer connected to the internet, or are you streaming from your personal collection of media?

Comment: This computer is connected to the internet. Incoming connections can only come to it from the outside world through port 80 (a very low-traffic webserver, mostly for my own personal junk) and port 22 (ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Your version is not suppported now. Meerkat support has been dropped on 10 of April.

Support droppage means there wont be any upgrades including security  updates.

If you are using it on server, you have to worry and certainly upgrade (I recommend Precise Pangolin since its an LTS release and its support period would last until 2017.

As more services you running as more dangerous your situation is.

Dont afraid of upgrading I am using Ubuntu many years and release to release upgrades never was problematic.

For Home Theater...well..I am dont think you have sensitive information on it and it wouldnt be a desirable target for hackers, unless its connected to Internet, its playing major role for you and it has a real IP with many open ports.

If you have Samba installed. Make sure you upgrade it to the latest as the is absolute serious security whole recently found.

**For the future**
Always use LTS versions for any type of servers.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment in the original question, the only open ports on this machine are 80 and 22. I do not use Samba with this machine.

Comment: then you can try to manually upgrade web server and SSH.

Comment: Or, get a beastly firewall.